# PigLatin Problems

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My Pig is running in MapReduce Mode. Now I am doing a join operation. There are three replications of a file in HDFS, How can I know which DataNode does the pig load data from?

I tried to use explain to display the plans.
But it only shows that data is loaded from hdfs://masterNodeIP:8020/data
Does this mean that all the data files need are loaded just from this masterNode?

Answer (score 0):

Open MapReduce administration web ui (typically http://masterNode:50030/) and find the job (you could identify it by id, pig logs it). Open it and you will see a bunch of map tasks, each assigned to a particular node from you cluster). Every map task corresponds to one HDFS block. MapReduce always tries to collocate task execution to the nodes, which store the corresponding block.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to explain read write process in Hadoop. Hope it will help you to understand your confusion.

**Data Write process on HDFS:**

The client machine first splits the file into block Say block A, Block B then client machine interact with NameNode to asks the location to place these blocks (Block A Block B).NameNode gives a list of datanodes to the clinet to write the data.

Then client choose first datanode from those list and write the first block to the datanode and datanode replicates the block to another datanode, once the second datanode receive the replicated block it gives the block received acknowledgement to primary datanode and the primary datanode update the block information to NameNode. NameNode keeps the information about files and their associated blocks.

You can look the blocks through the DFS browser, If you know the filename.

Go to your namenode web interface, say "browse the filesystem" and navigate to the file you're interested in. In the bottom of the page, there will be a list of all blocks in the file, and where each of those blocks is located.

Alternatively, you can run the command through command prompt:

```
hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -locations
```

To view the blocks for the specific file:

```
hadoop fsck [path] [options]
hadoop fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks
```

**Data read process from HDFS:**

When a client make a request to read data(user provide the file location or filename to read data), client interact to NameNode first and ask the location of of the data. NameNode returns the information about associated block and block location for that particular file then client directly interact with the datanode to get the block.

When you are processing the data through pig, hive or Map/Reduce, your job goes to that particular node and processing happens on that node where your data resides and after completion of the job you get the combined output.

This [link](http://www.slideshare.net/udayaprasad9/how-hadoop-exploits-data-locality) can be helpful to understand this.